# How to extract integer values from Array (of mixed types: integers/strings) via RegExp?

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex

I have an array:

```
arr2 = [6, '(7,0)', '(15,0)', '(5,0)', 3, '(15,2)', 17]
```

I want to parse each element of the array and get the value as follows:

```
arr2 = [6, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 17]
```

means if the array element is like (15,2) then only the second element i.e 2 should get printed in the response, and if the array element is not in the format like (7,0) then it should be printed as it is.

Comment: `arr2` is an invalid structure in Ruby.

Comment: @sagarpandya82, you can covert this array into a string type as follows:

arr2 = %w[6, (7,0), (15,0), (5,0), 3, (15,2), 17]

Comment: You’ve been told already that `[6, (7,0), (15,0), (5,0), 3, (15,2), 17]` is not a valid ruby object and you again come with it. Downvoted and voted to close.

Answer (score 3):

```
[6, [7,0], [15,0], [5,0], 3, [15,2], 17].map { |e| [*e].last }
#⇒ [6, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 17]
```

If the elements are strings:

```
%w[6, (7,0), (15,0), (5,0), 3, (15,2), 17].map { |e| e[/\d+(?=\)|,?\z)/] }
#⇒ ["6", "0", "0", "0", "3", "2", "17"]
```

`map(&:to_i)` the latter to get an array of integers.

---

Finally, for the up-to-date version:

```
[6, '(7,0)', '(15,0)', '(5,0)', 3, '(15,2)', 17].
    map { |e| e.to_s[/\d+(?=\)|,?\z)/] }.
    map(&:to_i)
#⇒ [6, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 17]
```

---

Exotics:

```
[6, '(7,0)', '(15,0)', '(5,0)', 3, '(15,2)', 17].
    inspect.
    scan(/\d+(?:,\d+)?/).
    map { |e| e.split(',').last.to_i }
#⇒ [6, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 17]
```

Comment: `%w` syntax does not require commas, just write `%w[6 (7,0) ...`

Comment: @akuhn “`%w` syntax does not require commas”—good to know, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
arr = [6, '(7,0)', '(15,0)', '(5,0)', 3, '(15,2)', 17]

arr.map do |obj|
  case obj
  when Integer
    obj
  else
    obj[/(?<=,)\d+/].to_i
  end
end
  #=> [6, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 17]
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems fine to me:

```
arr2.map{|x| x.to_s.scan(/\d+/).last.to_i }
```

And if you want something without regexp:

```
arr2.map do |item|
  item.is_a?(Integer) ? item : item[1+item.rindex(',')..-2].to_i 
end
```